# add querystring value on javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, window.open

how can i pass the value of my querystring into javacript ? that mean get the querystring on curent windows value and pass it into javascript to open a new page.

ex.: `/FicheClient.aspx?Item=Tarif&Id=850001` i want to pass Id=850001 into `window.open('Tarif_Report.aspx?Id=????')`

```
 <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton_RptTarif" runat="server" Text="Voir" AutoPostBack="False">
                          <ClientSideEvents
                            Click="function (s, e) { e.processOnServer = false; window.open('Tarif_Report.aspx?Id=????'); }" />
                        </dx:ASPxButton>
```

thanks you in advance.
Stev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 /*
* <summary>
* Get the querystring value
* </summary>
* <param name="key">A string contains the querystring key</param>
* <param name="defaultVal">Object which get returns when there is not key</param>
*
*/

function getQuerystring(key, defaultVal) {
    if (defaultVal == null) {
        defaultVal = "";
    }
    key = key.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + key + "=([^&#]*)");
    var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if (qs == null) {
        return defaultVal;
    }
    else {
        return qs[1];
    }
}
```

try This.

Answer (score 0):

Store the value of QueryString in Label or HiddenField, and get the stored value  from document.getElementById('Label').value. Pass this value in the window.open url.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a hold of the url using window.location.search

Check [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript#2880929) for a good answer for parsing the Querystring into something useful.

So with that you can access your param by going

```
window.open('/Tarif_Report.aspx?Id=' + urlParams["Id"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a public property in page.
2. During page load event set that property by getting the value from query string.
3. In ASPX page get the value using <% = this.PropertyName; %>

Answer (score 0):

i got it:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


        function getParameterByName(name)
        {
          name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
          var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
          var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
          var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
          if(results == null)
            return "";
          else
            return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
      </script>


     <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton_RptTarif" runat="server" Text="Voir" AutoPostBack="False">
                                                                    <ClientSideEvents
                                                                    Click="function (s, e) { e.processOnServer = false; window.open('../Tarif_Report.aspx?ClientID=' + getParameterByName('Id')); }" />
                                                                </dx:ASPxButton>
```

Thanks you all